# php artisan migrate throws received invalid response to SSL negotiation

Tags: laravel, postgresql, ssl, migrate

I have a laravel app on nginx with postresql

```
php artisan migrate
```

throws error:

```
In Connection.php line 671:
                                                                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] received invalid response to SSL negotiation: b (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = publ  
  ic and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')                                                                                
                                                                                                                                               

In Connector.php line 70:
                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] received invalid response to SSL negotiation: b
```

FILES:

.env

...

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=secretdbname
DB_USERNAME=secretusername
DB_PASSWORD=secretpassword
```

...

postresql.conf
...

```
port = 5432
```

...

in php.ini enabled:

```
pgsql
pdo_pgsql
mbstring
```

php -m

...

```
mbstring
openssl
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
```

...

Appropriate db exists, user exists and has got all the privileges.
Postgres service is active.
DB and app are located on the same server.

What I have tried:

- setting up a different port in both .env and postgres.conf
- tested with a different db, user and password
- restarted postresql
- in tinker DB::connection()->getPdo(); throws the same error
- in DB_HOST tried 127.0.0.1. instead of localhost
- in config/database.php i tried setting 'sslmode' to 'disable'

I have SSL certificate with certbot.

I would appreciate some hint on how to solve the above error.

Comment: please try `php artisan config:cache` and then run again. in tinker, test some config values like `env("DB_HOST")` or `env("DB_PORT")`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error today with the Laravel 9.

The solution was to make sure the Postgress DB_Port inside .env is pointing to 5432.

Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, following Alex running

```
php artisan config:cache
```

helped, as it thrown a slightly different error which pointed me to the actual solution

SOLUTION:

postgresql.conf file has got this line:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

commented by default, thus the solution is simply to uncomment it (as I mentioned in my original post, both DB and app are on the same server).

Hope it will save sb's time for the future.